# Form action problem with admin panel magento

Tags: forms, magento, panel, admin

hi
Guys I have a problem with form action of a form generated by admin panel of magento for a custom module.

This is the structure of my files under app/code/local/Namespace/Zipcodes/Block

```
Block
|
|____Adminhtml
    |
    |____ Importblock
        |
        |__Edit
        |   |__Form.php
        |   |__Tabs.php
        |   |
        |   |__Tab
        |       |___Form.php
        |
        |__Edit.php
        |
        |
        Zipcodes
        |
        |__Edit
        |   |__Form.php   // << this file is getting called in importblock form
        |   |__Tabs.php
        |   |
        |   |__Tab
        |       |___Form.php
        |
        |__Edit.php
```

This is my action method of ZipcodesController.php

```
public function importAction()
{

    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost() && isset($_FILES['csv_file']['name']) )
    {
        echo '<br> hi ! we  uploaded the file';
    }
    $this->_initAction();

    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('zipcodes/adminhtml_importblock_edit'))
          ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('zipcodes/adminhtml_importblock_edit_tabs'));

    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

This is my Block/Adminhtml/Importblock/Edit.php

```
<?php 
  class Namespace_Zipcodes_Block_Adminhtml_Importblock_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
   {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_objectId = 'id';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'zipcodes';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_zipcodes';
    $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('zipcodes')->__('Upload file'));

}

public function getHeaderText()
{   
    return Mage::helper('zipcodes')->__('Import Zipcode data');

}
```

}

This is my Block/Adminhtml/Importblock/Edit/Tab/Form.php

```
class Namespace_Zipcodes_Block_Adminhtml_Importblock_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
      {

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id' => 'edit_form',
            'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/import'),
            'method' => 'post',
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        )
    );
    $this->setForm($form);
    //echo '<br>form.php bahar<pre>';print_r(get_class_methods(get_class($form))); echo '</pre>';
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('zipcodes_form', array('legend'
                    => Mage::helper('zipcodes')->__('Provide data file')));

    $fieldset->addField('csv_file', 'file', array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('zipcodes')->__('CSV File'),
                    'class' => 'required-entry',
                    'required' => true,
                    'name' => 'csv_file',
            ));

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
 }
```

this is my Block/Adminhtml/Importblock/Edit/Tabs.php

```
class Namespace_Zipcodes_Block_Adminhtml_Importblock_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('zipcode_import_tabs');
    $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
    $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('zipcodes')->__('Import Zipcodes'));
}

protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    $this->addTab('form_section', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('zipcodes')->__('Zipcode Info'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('zipcodes')->__('Zipcode Info'),
            'content' => $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('zipcodes/adminhtml_importblock_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
            'active'    => true
        ));

    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
}
```

& last this is my Block_Adminhtml_Importblock_Edit_Form.php

```
class Namespace_Zipcodes_Block_Adminhtml_Importblock_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                'id' => 'edit_form',
                'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/import'),
                'method' => 'post',
            )
        );

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

when I run the code The last file doesn't gets called. as I am using `$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('zipcodes/adminhtml_importblock_edit'))` in code due to this when form gets rendered I see the form action action as /save instead of /import

So I changed the Block_Adminhtml_Importblock_Edit_Tab_Form & wrote

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id' => 'edit_form',
            'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/import'),
            'method' => 'post',
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        )
    );
```

But still its showing form action as /save not /import. Can anybody help me with this

---

Guys I have found one more clue

the file under Adminhtml/Zipcodes/Edit/Form.php is getting called in importblock's form
thats why the action is not getting set at runtime.
Now can anyone help me how to remove this error & make the correct reference to Adminhtml/Importblock/Edit/Form.php

Thanks Please its so close help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes a bit late but might be helpful for others that get this issue.

In your `Namespace_Zipcodes_Block_Adminhtml_Importblock_Edit` class you have:

```
$this->_objectId = 'id';
$this->_blockGroup = 'zipcodes';
$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_zipcodes';
```

but there is a property missing: `$this->_mode`

Setting `$this->_mode` to `'import'` will help you get the right action.

```
$this->_objectId = 'id';
$this->_blockGroup = 'zipcodes';
$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_zipcodes';
$this->_mode       = 'import'
```

After changing this you will get the right action for your form.

The default mode is `edit`:

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container extends     Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container
{
protected $_objectId = 'id';
protected $_formScripts = array();
protected $_formInitScripts = array();
protected $_mode = 'edit';
protected $_blockGroup = 'adminhtml';
```

the the function for _prepareLayout():

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    if ($this->_blockGroup && $this->_controller && $this->_mode) {
        $this->setChild('form', $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_blockGroup . '/' . $this->_controller . '_' . $this->_mode . '_form'));
    }
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

As you can see instead of your block, default you get the edit_form block.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

In your Namespace_Zipcodes_Block_Adminhtml_Importblock_Edit file, change this line:

```
$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_zipcodes';
```

to

```
$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_zipcodes_import';
```

That should do the trick.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Add this line before calling `setForm():`

```
   `$form->setUseContainer(true);`
```

This is a magic setter for the useContainer parameter of the _data array for this block. It's used to tell the admin form block widget to print out a  tag with the correct action url, as well as the hidden input used to verify the session.Varien, if you're listening, make this key true by default. Usually, with a form widget, you'd want a form tag to go with it as well.